# Headers en request a WebService

Tags: c#, webservice

Tengo un bot hecho en C# conectado a un Web Service. Para realizar un request de manera exitosa debo agregar varios headers, ¿Alguien puede decirme cómo hacerlo?

Comment: como estas realizando el request al web service? usas algun libreria estilo WebClient o HttpClient o creaste el Web Reference que crea el proxy para invocar el web method

Comment: Hasta ahora solo logré los request desde SoapUI, ya que ahí si pude agregar los headers, no tengo ni idea de cómo hacerlo desde el código. Busqué documentación o algo que hable de ello pero está difícil.

Comment: Si entendí lo que preguntaste añadí el Web Reference desde la opción "Agregar servicio conectado"

Answer (score 0):

Para asignar el header al servicio primero este debe definirlo

[Web Service in ASP.Net (Security by SOAP Authentication): Part 5](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8ef97c/web-service-in-Asp-Net-security-by-soap-authentication-pa/)

usemos el articulo de base, analiza el "Step 6", veras que se define la clase que hereda de `SoapHeader`

```
public class UserDetails : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeader  
{  
    public string userName { get; set; }  
    public string password { get; set; } 
}
```

entonces define el atributo en el webmethod

```
[WebService]  
public class MyServiceClass  
{  
     public UserDetails User;

     [WebMethod]  
     [SoapHeader("User", Required = true)]  
     public string SayHello(string userName)  
     {   
         //codigo
     }
 }
```

si ya lo tenias seguramente debas actualizar el `web reference`, entonces al instanciar podras asignar el dato del header